# "Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to train a model, but I am getting this error

> Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Here's part of my code, how can I fix this?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

a = clean_df.drop('AQI_calculated', axis = 1).values
b = clean_df.loc[:, 'AQI_calculated'].values


a_train, a_test, b_train, b_test = train_test_split(a, b, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(a_train, b_train)
```

Comment: check your data for NaN or infinity, and replace / fill / remove as required

Answer (score 3):

You have to check if in your data you have `NaN` values basically. **A model can't be trained if there are some NaN, infinity or a value to large** (as the error says).

To check I reccomend you using this code:

```
df.isnull().any().any()  #This code tells you if you have some NaN value in you dataframe
```

If you want to know in which column these `NaN` values are, you can do it this way:

```
df.isnull().any()
```

Once you know where `NaN` values are, you should have to deal with them. You can simple remove, fill or replace as *@kelvt* suggest in the comment.